# Trying to update captions with a PUT route (node.js/express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, express, ejs

I'm trying to update the caption column in my post table through using a form on an `update.ejs` page.

For some reason, it just redirects me back to my `index.ejs` page without updating my database. Can anyone spot anything wrong with my routes or ejs page?

Here are my update routes:

```
app.get('/update', (req, res) => {
  console.log(res.locals.alerts);
  res.render('update', { alerts: res.locals.alerts });
});

// update caption
app.put('/update', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  console.log('--- PUT route ---');
  // console.log(req.body.id)
  // const id = req.body.id
  db.post.update({
    caption: req.body.caption
  }, {
    where: { id: req.body.id }
  }).then(() => {
    res.redirect('/')
  })
})
```

Here is the `update.ejs`:

```
<form action="/update?_method=put" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" value="<%= post.id %>" name="caption" placeholder="New Caption:" id="updatePostText" >
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="postSubmit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your submitting an html form using the http method `POST`, in your express-app you are using `.put` for your route, so you should change the latter to:

```
app.post('/update', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => { ... }
```